# Signalr Increase the number of IIS requests

Tags: iis-7.5, signalr

I have an application which I 've used signalr. Application is working fine. But the problem is it is increasing the number of IIS requests when I pushed data using Signalr. 
Is there any way to automatically end the request once the pushed the data. ( Is there any mechanism in Signalr to do that?)

Comment: Could you just close the SignalR connection on the client side after you receive the data you've pushed?

Comment: This is a call center type application. Client have to listen all the time to server for messages

Comment: SignalR should only have one ongoing request setup to receive messages at any given time once a connection has been established. It's possible that there could be more simultaneous requests if the client is also sending messages to the server, but only up to one additional request per message being processed. There should not be any requests piling up. If there are, this question needs way more details about which requests are ongoing.